# adding text to another programs text box c++

Tags: c++, sendmessage

i have already managed to send text to a custom text box i created using c++, and to notepad, calc and other programs all with 1 window and 1 text box. however, i want to send text to another program that has more than one text box and is in tabs too. it is structured like so:

1. open program
2. choose from a selection of 2 tabs: a. stats b. config(which contains the text boxes)
3. fill in the 4 text boxes to desired values

i have tried winspy++ with no luck, here is simple code i have been working with.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{ 
HWND hNote;
HWND hChild;

if (!(hNote=FindWindow("windowname",NULL)))
    exit(1);

if (!(hChild=FindWindowEx(hNote,NULL,"EDIT",NULL)))
    exit(2);

SendMessage(hChild,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)"texttoadd");

return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me how can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Spy++ is exactly the tool that will help you find the child window hierarchy. Why did you have "no luck"?

Comment: i made a mistake when reading the results from winspy, i made sure i had the correct handle by using wm_gettext. however, there is now another problem, the handle changes every time the program is closed and reopened.

Answer (score 5):

So the problem is to get a handle of the specific control. You may use for example following ways for finding control's handle:

- Control can be distinguished by control id, then use [GetDlgItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) function to get the its handle. Control id can be found using tools like Spy++ or InqSoft Windows Scanner or other.
- MSDN says that control can be found by coordinates of the point within parent window by [ChildWindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676.aspx) , [ChildWindowFromPointEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632677.aspx) or [RealChildWindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633537.aspx) function.
- Or all controls can be enumerated within parent window by [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) and an appropriate one can be found using custom rules.